# AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute 'view_init'

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, 3d

I am trying to make an animation of a 3D plot rotating and have tried "replicating" several codes I have seen on here but always get an attribute error. Firstly my image is made using the following line
`ax= pp.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d').scatter(x, y, z, c=surface[:,3], s=75, cmap = 'jet', alpha=0.4)`

Which is probably a bit messy but I am unfamiliar with matplotlib, however when trying various codes found here and other sites I get various attribute errors (I work in jupyter if that's a problem).
Trying to use

```
for angle in range(0, 360):
            ax.view_init(30)
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(.001)
```

throws "AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute 'view_init'"

However using:

```
    ax.view_init(azim=angle)
def different_function
   rot_animation = animation.FuncAnimation(ax, rotate, frames=np.arange(0,362,2),interval=100)
   rot_animation.save('path/rotation.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

throws "AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute 'canvas'". I am beginning to think my installation of matplotlib is bugged or something.

Comment: Even tried using Axes3d.view_init from mplot3d and got a new unique attribute error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dist'.

Comment: Please only call things `ax` that are an actual axes. This will prevent you from trying to use axes methods on objects that are something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested the answer was just to be consistent in which/what module I was using to create the figure and axes, using Axes3D to create the axis and ffmpeg as the movie writer to save the animation worked just fine. 
Final code was essentially

```
def rotate(angle):
     ax = plt.gca()
     ax.view_init(elev=15, azim=angle)

def random3dplottingfunction() 
     #bunch of junk to generate the plot
     ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = surface[:,3], s=20, cmap = 'jet', alpha=0.65)
    animate= animation.FuncAnimation(fig, rotate, frames=range(0,360,1),interval=100)
    animate.save('animate'+str(top)+str(i)+'.mp4', fps=10)
```

This worked just fine.

Comment: Also I'm not much of a coder so I should probably have said library instead of module but hopefully everyone gets the gist, I'll figure out proper terms after the code works.